# Dot in column name - Spark Sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I am translating an existing Athena query to a Glue Spark job using the AWS Visual ETL. They both will query from the same underlying Glue table, say, `glue_table`. This table has many columns and some of them are named like `a.b.c` with strings with several dots in it.

The existing Athena query has the SQL statement:

```
Select "a.b.c" from glue_table
```

and it works just fine. However, I cannot seem to make it work in the Spark SQL syntax provided to me by the Visual ETL UI after I provide my query. The snippet goes like:

```
...
AWSGlueDataCatalog_node = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame(
        database = "my_database",
        table_name = "glue_table",
        ....
)

SQLQuery = sparkSqlQuery(
"""
select " how to select my dotted column" from my glue_table
"""
)
.....
```

I have tried several different suggestions by googling, such as `'a.b.c', "a.b.c"` and the backticks inside and outside the single/double quotation marks etc. The apache spark sql page has no documentation on this whatsoever.

What to do short of renaming the columns in the table, since the Athena query is just fine ??